# Android vector drawable wrong rendering

Tags: android, vector, android-vectordrawable

I have many image views that use a vector drawable. And with complicated vector it shows up distorted after several taps.

Can anyone explain why and how to fix it?

My build gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    renderscriptTargetApi 25
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
```

The result shows exactly as this sample:

[image]

Comment: Which version of support library are you using? Because this has been solved in Support Library v25.0.0

Comment: I am using Support Library v25.2.0. This error occurs only when I make some actions back and forth.

Comment: i think you found a bug which should be reported in the issue tracker. The main problem could be the conversion between the vector and the bitmap while in presence of complex vector icons